# Input/output values into an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

EDIT: Updated question using some of the suggestions below. This produces weird output though.

```
Dim ProviderArray() As Variant

Sub GetProviderNumbers()
Dim InputRange As Range
Dim WorkRange As Range


Set InputRange = Range("ProviderList")

Set WorkRange = Application.Intersect(InputRange, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

SizeOfArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(WorkRange)

ReDim ProviderArray(0 To SizeOfArray)

ProviderArray = WorkRange.Value

For r = 1 To UBound(ProviderArray, 1)
For C = 1 To UBound(ProviderArray, 2)
    Debug.Print r, C, ProviderArray(r, C)
Next C
Next r

End Sub
```

1             1             5555 
 2             1             4444654 
 3             1             654654 
 4             1             654654654 
 5             1
 6             1
 7             1
 8             1
 9             1
 10            1
 11            1
 12            1
 13            1
 14            1
 15            1
 16            1
 17            1
 18            1
 19            1

Could someone explain why this output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use the one-line approach if you put the range into a 2-D array: you only have a 1-D array.

You could do this:

```
Dim ProviderArray()
Set WorkRange = .Intersect(InputRange, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

'This makes ProviderArray a 2-D array, dimension 1 = # rows,
'   dimension2 = #cols.  Both dimensions are 1-based.  
ProviderArray = WorkRange.value 

for r=1 to ubound(ProviderArray,1)
for c=1 to ubound(ProviderArray,2)
    debug.print r,c,ProviderArray(r,c)
next c
next r
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `for c=1 to ...` line use `ubound(ProviderArray,2)` instead of `,1`?

Comment: Trying using this but don't understand my output.

Comment: It just prints each value in the array to the immediate window: row#, col#, value

Comment: I changed debug.print r,c,ProviderArray(r,c) to debug.print ProviderArray(r) and it tells me it's subscript out of range. Why is that? I'm trying to mimic the following (Assume C++ programming language) for(x = 0; x < arrayLen; x++){ cout << array[x]}

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept the answer it worked for the most part; that being said my excel document [that only has this macro and a database table] just got corrupted and doesn't do anything now. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something a bit simpler like:

```
Private Sub GetProviderNumbers()

    Dim InputRange() As Variant
    InputRange = Range("ProviderList")

    For Each i In InputRange
        Debug.Print i
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This captures a two-dimensional range and stores the values in a global two-dimensional array:

```
Dim ProviderArray() As String
Sub MAIN()
Range("B2:C11").Name = "ProviderList"
Call GetProviderNumbers
End Sub
Sub GetProviderNumbers()
    ary = Range("Providerlist")
    ll = LBound(ary, 1)
    lm = LBound(ary, 2)
    ul = UBound(ary, 1)
    um = UBound(ary, 2)
    ReDim ProviderArray(ll To ul, lm To um)
    For i = ll To ul
        For j = lm To um
            ProviderArray(i, j) = ary(i, j)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```